# How do I draw onto Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I wish to be able quickly to outline areas on Google Maps, then print (or even better save) a rectangle of the map that contains the given area. For example, I wish to outline a school playing field, then save the image that contains the school, the road it is on and the outlined playing field.

Is there a standard solution for this anywhere?

<sub>Taking a screen dump and using MS-Paint is too slow for the number of areas I need to outline.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found [Scribblemaps](http://www.scribblemaps.com/)

It seems to do what you want.

There's also [My Maps](http://maps.google.com/help/maps/mymaps/create.html) in Google Maps itself. There's a help topic [here](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=21670&topic=21676).

> Depending on your location, you can create personalized, annotated, customized maps using Google Maps. Your maps can contain the following:
>
> - Placemarks
> - Lines
> - Shapes

Answer (score 1):

I usually use Google My Maps for when the "map" I create is of interest to limited other users.

If I want my "map" to be published (eventually) to the rest of the world I use [Google Map Maker](http://www.google.com/mapmaker) (GMM), provided that my country is one of those [open for GMM editing](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=155415). Currently, 181 countries are open.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this Chrome extension: [Web Paint](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-paint/emeokgokialpjadjaoeiplmnkjoaegng).

> Draw shapes, lines, and add text to the current webpage and take screenshot.